# Why would a white space change the meaning of a sentence in auto hotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Recently I noticed a problem that it seems when I call a function with a white space included, the function call won't work correctly.Example:

```
while true
{
    tooltip, % getkeystate ("lbutton","p")
    ;tooltip, % getkeystate("lbutton","p")
}
return
```

the code commented works correctly showing 1 or 0 ,but the former one always shows "lbutton", which confused me a lot, I wonder:
1.What causes the difference?
2.What is the syntax of the former one?Why would it return the key name?
3.When would a white space affect the meaning of a sentence?

Comment: Is this `C#`, or a different language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in the first one, the tooltip evaluates the expression which in this case starts with the empty variable `getkeystate` and then returns the quoted string `lbutton` so that is what the tootltip shows.

The second one evaluates a function `getkeystate(parameters)` to put in the tooltip.